# add items to a list c# Wpf

Tags: c#

I have list, listbox, buttony textbox.

My idea is to do that by clicking on the button, the content of the text box is added to the list and then passing the data to a list box.

My problem is if you add what I write, but the elements that are in the list box are overwritten with the new one that you insert. and I just want to add more articles. to the list and to go to the list box. Thank you very much for your answers. This is the code of my button:

```cs
private void button54_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox3.Text != '')
    {
        List<Playlists> List1 = new List<Playlists>();
        List1.Add(new Playlists(textBox3.Text, @rutaalbum));
        lbPlaylist.ItemsSource = List1;
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Please post the code via copy paste. Never post images of code. There are tons of reasons for that. I wonder that no one else has written it yet

Comment: Your problem is that you create each time a new list. So your list will have always only one item and it exists only in the scope of the click method. You need to pull out the declaration of the list from the method into the class level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to maintain a list and bind the list to a listbox. Then be able to add to the list with a button. I found that I had to unbind by setting the ItemSource to null and rebind to get the new items added to the list to show up in the listbox.

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
        private void btnAddToList_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mylist.Add(txtList.Text);
            ListBox1.ItemsSource = null;
            ListBox1.ItemsSource = mylist;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a list :

```
 List<string> mylist = new List<string>
```

To add items to the list :

```
 mylist.Add(textbox1.Text)
```

To add items to the `ListBox` from the list :

```
 foreach(string item in mylist)
 {
  ListBoxItem itm = new ListBoxItem();
  itm.Content = item;

  listbox.Items.Add(itm);
 }
```

Hope this helps you :)